# What is correct in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

1. I died (of laughter) when I read this.
2. I have died when I read this.

Which sentence is correct?

EDIT: Of course not literally

Comment: Hello Jasonson, welcome to our community. As you've noticed, comments are not used for answers but to make suggestions and ask for clarification. Michael made a fair point about the examples you used in your question (the used of "died" is a slightly odd choice to ask about a past/perfect tense) It's best not to say things like "If you don't know the answer..." Remember that you aren't owed an answer. Nobody is getting paid to help you.

Comment: We have quite a few other questions about past/ present perfect tense.  You could explain what is particular to this question that makes it hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You use the simple past tense for an event that happened at a definite time in the past, e.g. indicated by 'when'.

> I **died** (figuratively) when I read this
>
> I **saw** a bird when I looked out of the window
>
> I **felt** a sharp pain when the dog bit my hand

[Use of the simple past](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/simple_past_use.htm)

It may be worth noting that 'die' has a strong default meaning of 'cease to be alive', and following that no purposeful activity is possible. When native speakers wish to use it figuratively to mean something like 'feel or react strongly' they will very often use qualifying words such as 'just', 'practically', 'nearly', etc - I just died when my father sat on the whoopee cushion; I practically died of laughter when I read that book; I nearly died of embarassment when my mother found my dirty books. Failure to do this will be seen as careless by many speakers.

Comment: I didn't mention the annoyance felt by some people when 'literally' is used to mean 'figuratively' in (e.g.) 'I literally died of cold waiting for a bus this morning'.